# GDI Graphics in a dialog

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, dialog, gdi

I've written a Vis. Studio dialog app to remotely control a piece of equipment that includes a small LCD graphic display that we need to view from the dialog. The V.Studio dialog editor doesn't seem to provide a canned solution. Being a Windows programmer by need rather than avocation, what I've done is:

- Added an edit control to the dialog.
- When an LCD image update arrives, create a CClientDC on the edit control
- Call GDI functions to set pixel values

This seems bletcherous but does work when the image arrives. Obviously doesn't redraw the image when the dialog is redrawn. The code saves the image data for a redraw, but no joy attempting to find some place to call the image redraw function when the dialog is redrawn.

- Adding a redraw call as the last statement in the dialog OnPaint() function creates the image, but it is immediately wiped out when OnPaint() returns.
- Same result when posting a custom WM_DRAWLCD_MESSAGE in OnPaint() - Image is created, but wiped out.
- Framework doesn't appear to call EndPaint(), so can't redraw the image there.

Two questions:
1. Is there a generally-accepting method of accomplishing this end?
2. If not, where can the code place a call to a redraw function when the dialog is redrawn?

@zeromus: [image: LCD Image]
My "toaster" is connected to the dialog app and communicating quite well. The LCD image in question is the content of an LCD panel mounted on the machine for operator use. When I'm diagnosing remotely it will be simpler to do so by clicking the dialog button controls under the image to perform control/status operations and see the response, rather than duplicating all the machine functions by some other means. Things work as expected as long as the dialog remains on top. When the dialog doesn't remain on top, bringing it back on top doesn't restore the image - The data and code creating the bitmap aren't part of a CEdit control. So the questions are (1) Is there a wizard-approved way to display and restore a changing bitmapped image in a dialog app (as opposed to displaying a static image) and (2) If not, is there some place in the dialog code to splice in a call to my bitmap-drawing function during a redraw of the dialog?  Thanks!

Comment: Solution is simple: Add a `CBitmap` object as a member to your dialog class. Whenever data arrives, update the bitmap data, and call `InvalidateRect` to trigger an update. In your `OnPaint`-handler, simply render the bitmap. If you need a placeholder in your dialog resource, use an invisible static control. Since you are all obsessed with the use of the MFC wizard you should consider taking two steps back: `1` Learn the Windows API, and `2` Get to know the MFC preprocessor macros in depth. If you skip either step, MFC will make Windows programming significantly harder.

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind I haven't used MFC since the day .net was released, a strategy I suggest you go back in time and copy, the normal way to do this in windows would be to maintain a CBitmap containing the contents of the LCD. Then simply draw it in the OnPaint--directly onto the dialog would be easiest. In Windows, you're supposed to do all your drawing on OnPaint, but you can do anything you want ahead of time to be ready. Your involvement of the Edit control can't possibly be helping anything.

Since it's requiring absurdly cryptic steps to draw things in windows even with MFC, I'll paste my test code. This may offend MFC veterans, but it gets the job done, give or take same object lifetime management. It may contain subtle bugs since everything's so hard, but it shows the principle of painting a bitmap. Also if you're drawing to the background of the dialog after all, you might wish to do it in the "erasebackground" event, I don't know.

```
//create bitmap with updated contents
bmp = new CBitmap();
bmp->CreateCompatibleBitmap(this->GetDC(), 100,100);
__int32* buf = (__int32*)malloc(100*100*4);
int r=rand(),g=rand(),b=rand(),a=255;
for(int y=0;y<100;y++) for(int x=0;x<100;x++) buf[y*100+x] = b|(g<<8)|(r<<16)|(a<<24);
bmp->SetBitmapBits(100*100*4,buf);
free(buf);

//when painting
CPaintDC dc(this);
CDC bitmapDC;
bitmapDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc); 
bitmapDC.SelectObject(bmp);
dc.BitBlt(0,0,100,100,&bitmapDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
```

Comment: Mixing `malloc` and `new` is awkward. Creating a compatible bitmap, and then ignoring the bitdepth is a bug. Not accounting for scanline alignment is a bug as well. Suggesting to use `CPaintDC` in a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message handler is wrong. There's really very little useful information hidden between lots of wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable is the bitmap from `CreateCompatibleBitmap` not guaranteed to be 32 bit for modern displays? The correct usage here should be `bmp->CreateBitmap(100, 100, 1, 32, buf)` but if the monitor doesn't support 32 bit then it's the same problem.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: `CreateCompatibleBitmap` returns a bitmap, that's *compatible* with the provided device context. This is not the same as a *device independent* bitmap. The correct usage is to use a compatible bitmap, and implement code using the requested bit depth.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all the awful minutiae required to do this fully correctly in win32 and MFC.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, they are appreciated. Re. the disdain for using MFC, I make a living by designing and building embedded control systems, not by building Windows apps. This is the first instance of MFC editors and wizards not meeting my simple needs since I began writing Windows hacks with Visual C++ 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here's what's working for me:

Add two member variables to the dialog class:

  CImage  m_lcdImage;
  CStatic m_lcdStatic;

In the init dialog callback:

  m_lcdStatic.Create( "Static",
    WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP | SS_CENTERIMAGE, 
    CRect( <rectangle coordinates> ), this );

  m_lcdImage.Create( <bitmap extent + color depth> );
  m_lcdStatic.SetBitmap( HBITMAP( m_lcdImage ));
  drawLCD();

Add member function drawLCD() called in init or when bitmap changes:

{
  //
  // app-specific m_lcdImage.SetPixel() calls 
  // to update the bitmap
  //

  m_lcdStatic.InvalidateRect( NULL );
}
```